# Database structure for application, offer, and accepted offer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, associations

I am trying to set up my database for a rails 4 website that has two types of users, one of which fills out applications and the other which makes offers on the applications - one of which, the applicant would accept.

My problem is figuring out how to go about having "accepted offers". Should "accepted offers" be an entirely different table? Should I make an "is accepted" column in my "offer" table? or is there some other way I could go about this?

Comment: The question I would ask is does the accepted answer change the behavior? Does a user with an accepted_offer do things differently then other users? If so, I would either make them a separate model or a type [using single table inheritance](http://eewang.github.io/blog/2013/03/12/how-and-when-to-use-single-table-inheritance-in-rails/) if not, I would make it a boolean column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would place a column on the applications table named "accepted_offer_id" that references the offer that has been accepted.

This guarantees that the number of accepted offers is either 0 or 1, and avoids having to implement a slightly tricky bit of logic to ensure that only one offer per application can have an "is_accepted" value of true.

It also easily permits a new association of the applications table for "belongs_to :accepted_offer"